# Multiple phrases per language in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, localization

I am creating a website using CakePHP that requires translation not only into multiple languages but also multiple phrases per language depending on the type of the logged in user.  This will allow the same functionality but with more formal or more friendly language without duplication.

As a very simple example:

- Type 1: "Customer", "purchase","shopping cart"
- Type 2: "Client", "buy", "basket"
- Type 3: "User", "order","invoice"

Each of these types would be available in multiple languages.

I've got the standard localization working in CakePHP (one of the reasons I chose it!) and have the appropriate default.po files in the /Locale/[lang]/LC_MESSAGES/ directory and all is working fine there (thank you to the user who noted on this site that ger needed to be deu to work ;) ).

Before I get too far into the app I'd like to add the phrasing so I can set e.g. the language as French and phrasing as type2.  If I was doing this outside of a framework I'd have a matrix look-up to find the correct string based on language and phrase keys but am unsure of how to do this within CakePHP's localization.

Currently I'm using the standard __([string]) convention but as this is early in the development cycle it would be trivial to change if necessary.

I was considering using __d([phrase],[string]) but can't see how to set this without creating my app as a plugin and then I'm back to the same problem with /Locale/

I have been unable to find any example of this in my searches on SO or the cakePHP community sites so would be grateful for any suggestions.

Is there a standard way to do this within cakePHP?  if not, what would be a good "best practice" way to implement this?

**Edit** - following the answer below here's how it was implemented:

in /app/Locale/[lang]/LC_MESSAGES/ I created a new .po files with the new phrasing in them as phrase1.po, phrase2.po etc.

Where I set the language I also set the phrasing where the phrase file matches the name of the po file:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');
Configure::write('App.langDomain', 'phrase1');
```

and all strings were wrapped with:

```
__d(Configure::read('App.langDomain', 'string')
```

And it just works.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback as to why this was down voted please - I believe the question was clear and I could not find a duplicate.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use __d() like this:

```
__d(Configure::read('App.langDomain'), 'Some string');
```

In bootstrap.php check the conditions and set App.langDomain based on whatever you need.

__d() has nothing to do with plugins, you can use it everywhere.

And alternative would be to wrap your translations with a custom method, something like

```
__dd(Configure::read('App.langDomain'), array('foo' => __('String1', 'bar' => __('String2'));
```

The array is an array of langDomain => stringForThatDomain mappings. Your __dd() method would take the one that is passed in the first argument.

Comment: Many thanks - knew there would be something simple that would "just work" :) .

Comment: @Yssybyl To prevent having to set the domain for every string using `__d(..)`, it's also possible to change the default domain; e.g. `I18n::$defaultDomain = 'my domain';`